# Not able to deploy gitlab private repo to cpanel

Tags: yaml, gitlab-ci.yml

---

deployment:
script:
- export DEPLOYPATH=/home/renewsmsproteamc/public_html/gitrepo/
- /bin/cp * $DEPLOYPATH

I'm using this YML Code to auto deploy from gitlab repo to live server but it is giving error like below.

/bin/cp: target '/home/renewsmsproteamc/public_html/gitrepo/': No such file or directory

I tried all yml but it is not working.

Comment: Did you check whether the folder exists? To me, this problem looks completely unrelated to [tag:yaml] or [tag:gitlab-ci.yml]

Comment: YES Folder is there.